# Wifi Multi-AP Roaming, connected to single authentication server

Tags: wireless-networking, wpa2-psk, radius

We are thinking of setting up a configuration where 10 or so wifi APs are setup in our building all with the same SSID for roaming, connected to a wired ethernet for backhaul.

Our solution requires a WPA2 password per user - would be grateful if anyone could recommend any good open source Radius solutions/complimentary good APs that can provide server based authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Easy answer, use dd-wrt ap's with pfsense and freeradius with EAP caching. It supports real time application roaming. You may have to tinker with the ap's if they are broadcom chipsets. I would personally recommend sticking with the exact same model across all access points. And if you can use atheros ap's and wireless cards. It will save you from tinker frustration getting it up and running. (Also make sure all your ap's are running the same revision of dd-wrt)